# Avoiding duplication of namespace elements in python imports

Tags: python, namespaces, python-import

This is probably a vestige from my days as a c# programmer, and I probably just need to learn the "pythonic" way of doing things.  I'm relatively new to python, but have been coding in c# for years.

I have a python module within my project named 'applib' where I store a number of classes.  Each class is contained within its own file of the same name (e.g. Foo.py has a class named Foo, Bar.py has a class named Bar, etc).

When I want to use a class, I have to say

```
import applib.Foo
```

followed by something like

```
my_foo=applib.Foo.Foo()
```

This results in having to specify "Foo" twice in my declaration (once for the module name, and then again for the class).  In c# I could control this with a namespace directive at the top of the class file, but in python I don't know of a way to control this except for putting all my classes in a single file. I know I can also import the class by using

```
from applib.Foo import Foo
```

but that's still a duplication of namespace elements, which I want to avoid completely.

Can anyone provide me with some recommendations on a more pythonic methodology for namespace structure within an app?

Comment: don't write one module per class. Put all your classes in `applib`.

Comment: "Each class is contained within its own file of the same name" - bad idea. It causes all sorts of confusion, including mixing up classes and modules, and making things like circular import problems much more common.

Comment: @Daniel.  I'm confused.  How would I set my directory structure up to reflect this?